# how to parse associative JSON arrays in QT?

Tags: c++, json, qt

I would like to know, how to parse associative JSON arrays in QT.

This is my example JSON:

```
{
    "req_code": 5,
    "params": {
        "email":"user@domain.com",
        "password":"123"
    }
}
```

So, in order to get *email* (from JSON string called 'data') I would have to do something like this:

```
QJsonDocument doc=QJsonDocument::fromJson(data.toUtf8());
QJsonObject jobj=doc.object();
QJsonValue params_value=jobj.value(QString("params"));
QJsonArray params_array=params_value.toArray();
```

Now, 'email' is being held in 'params_array' object, but this array is not a QHash and not a QMap. If it would be a QHash I would get email by:

```
QString email=params_array.value("email");
```

But it is not a hash, it is a vector. So how do I get the value of 'email' property in this case in a proper and fast way?

Comment: In your JSON example, the value of `params` is an object, not an array.

Comment: @O'Neil Ok. By any chance do you know how can I get a QJsonObject from `jobj` variable which is also a QJsonObject type ? The docs do not have any method like that, most methods are returning QJsonValue.

Comment: You just have to convert your `QJsonValue params_value` to a QJsonObject with [QJsonValue::toObject()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#toObject-1) instead of a QJsonArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `params` is an object, and `QJsonObject` provides [map-like functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#operator-5b-5d-2) so you can easily access it:

```
auto doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data.toUtf8());
auto docObj = doc.object();
auto paramsObj = docObj["params"].toObject();
auto email = paramsObj["email"];
```

And [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html#the-json-classes) says:

> All JSON classes are value based, implicitly shared classes.

so you don't really need to take much care of performance. If you want to conver `QJsonObject` to hash or map, you can use [`QJsonObject::toVariantHash`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#toVariantHash) or [`QJsonObject::toVariantMap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#toVariantMap).

Comment: sorry for the question, but what are "value based" classes ? Can't find any docs in google about it.

Comment: That means everything is pass by value. For example, `QJsonValue::toObject` returns a new object by value, not by reference. However the object is _implicitly shared_ , only internal pointer is copied and you don't need to worry about performance.

Comment: thank you very much, compiled and tested my code, it works perfectly, just as I wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
        QJsonArray params_array = jobj.value("params").toArray();
        qDebug() << "params_array:: results array size = " << params_array.count();
        foreach (const QJsonValue & value, a)
        {
            QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();
            qDebug() << "obj keys " << obj.keys() ;
            // here you can access your data, verify your keys with the debug a
        }
```

Comment: but you are scanning through the whole array searching for the key here. For long arrays this is inefficient. Aren't there any form to convert JSON array to QHash or QMap ?